# How do I pipe the result of previous command to node as a variable?

Tags: shell, pipe

I'm trying to create a script to decode data from redis. I can make this a node script but I just wanted it to be as simple as possible.

Here's what I got so far.

```
redis-cli GET "d1g8y" | xargs -i node -e "require('zlib').gunzip(Buffer.from('{}', 'base64'), function(err, string) { console.log(string.toString()); })"
```

And it doesn't work. How do I get the result from this command `redis-cli GET "d1g8y"` and put that into this script `Buffer.from('$VARIABLE_FROM_PREVIOUS_COMMAND', 'base64')`

This is how I compressed the data

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

const zipAsync = Promise.promisify(zlib.gzip, {context: zlib});
return zipAsync(Buffer.from(value)).then(console.log);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use `node` at all?  Kind of deer hunting with a howitzer, no?

```
redis-cli GET "d1g8y" | zcat | base64 --decode
```

`zcat` will transmogrify gzipped data into plaintext, which in your case happens to be a base64-encoded string, so we simply pipe that into the decoder.

Comment: I didn't know this command at all. Thanks. But I got this error when trying to do this.

`echo 'H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WOsQ2AMAwEV0GumYAaBgnYSiyCjRxTIMTuOCPw5Z10+gdWxRsmaHqQF5YMIxRKGIjFyah5wKGjykJhkfaQVf8tGkhtMz6dVSKTLi9qUZqTp2GRHHWyfuD9ALqyV6uVAAAA' | zcat | base64 --decode
`

Comment: I use gzip to compress the data. I'll edit the question to show how I compress the data

Comment: In your `echo` test, you're not sending gzipped data to zcat, so it fails on you.  To emulate the unzipping-into-decode, use `echo | gzip | zcat | base64`.  Or, to emulate the full stack, plaintext to encode to compress to uncompress to decode to plaintest:  `echo "asdf" | base64 | gzip | zcat | base64 --decode` (which is probably the most convoluted `echo` I've done in a long, long time (: ).